# Call one scenario from another - Specflow

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, specflow, gherkin

I have a gherkin and specflow script that registers a user, then in the same script I need to get into an external resource to get the verification code.... If I break it all into 2 different scripts, can I somehow call one scenario in another or is it impossible, if you do it manually in code it generates a lot of unnecessary dependencies?

I tried dividing into different ones, but they did not interact in any way, I tried to manually call all the steps from another script in the code itself, but this is not the best approach due to unnecessary dependencies

Comment: SpecFlow wrote a guide specifically for this: [How to call one scenario from another? Embrace Shared Steps](https://specflow.org/challenges/call-one-scenario-from-another/).

Comment: A simple google search for **specflow call one scenario from another** had the link above as the first match.